# I cannot connect buttons to any outlets or actions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

On my swift project, I have two view controllers. On the second view controller, I cannot create any outlets, actions, or outlet collections with the buttons. When I drag the buttons to ViewController.swift, I can't place the button anywhere to create an outlet or an action.

When I write out the action / outlet with @IBAction etc. I can't connect it to my buttons on the second view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't set the Class in the Identity Inspector. Select the view controller in the storyboard for which you want to establish outlets, open the Utilities panel, go to the Identity Inspector, and make sure your "Class" is set.

If you haven't added a second subclass of UIViewController to your project yet, you probably want to cmd-n -> iOS Source -> Cocoa Touch Class and then put in a name and make it a subclass of UIViewController (I am assuming your second view controller is a UIViewController and not a UITableViewController or something else). Then you can set your second view controller's class to this by doing what I described in the first paragraph.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. I had already set the class and even after I added the new cocoa touch class it wouldn't work.

Comment: @jpegger What is your "Class" set to now for the second view controller?

Comment: I have it set to UIView

Comment: @jpegger That's the problem; it needs to be set to a subclass of UIViewController, not UIView. What is the name of the new cocoa touch class that you added? Check to make sure that in the `class` line of that class you see `class NameOfYourViewController: UIViewController {` If you do, go back to the storyboard, select the second view controller so that there is a blue outline around it (click the yellow icon right above it), go to the Identity inspector, and start typing the name of your new cocoa touch UIViewController subclass

Comment: @jpegger When you start typing the name there (in the Class spot in the Identity Inspector), it should fill in the rest of the name automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry it took me so long to understand :]